# R basics - optimal code letter grades using for and i

Tags: r

I am trying to create a list of letter grades based on total subject scores.
I am using the following code:

```
def getLetterGrade(score):
   score = round(subject_total)
grades = [(80,'A'), (70,'B'), (60,'C'), (50,'D'), (0,'F')]
for i in range(len(grades)):
   if score >= grades[i][0]:
   return grades[i][1]
```

I am getting an error unexpected symbol in each line except for the score = line
Can someone please help?
Sorry - new to R

Comment: The `grades` you showed is a python object

Comment: You need to tab the lines. ie, grades should be directly under score and everything after should be directly after score. Just align your code accordingly

Comment: Also this is python and note R. You used the wrong tag

Comment: Try: `cut(scores, breaks=c(0, 50, 60, 70, 80, Inf), labels=c("F", "D", "C", "B", "A"), right=FALSE)`. R is vectorized, so with a the `cut()` function no need for loops or if statements.